# Resources Plugin dependency for another Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to build an Grails plugin on top of Resources Plugin. Basically it's just a ResourceMapper. So, I need to use `MapperPhase` enum.

I've tried to add following into `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
    build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
          ":release:2.0.3",
          ":rest-client-builder:1.0.2") {
        export = false
    }
    runtime(":resources:1.1.6")
}
```

*tried also compile(":resources:1.1.6"), but same result*

As I see, it's pretty standard practice for *resources based* plugins, and should works. Btw, when I'm trying to run main application, it fails with:

```
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
  ***/XXXResourceMapper.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.MapperPhase
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.MapperPhase
```

And also, I'm using Intellij IDEA, and it can't resolve this enum as well.

How I should specify dependency to Resources Plugin at this case?

PS In main Grails application, that uses this plugin, i'm using local plugins definition (like `grails.plugin.location.'XXX-resources' = 'XXX'`). If it's matter.

Comment: I got the same error after upgrading to Twitter bootstrap plugin to 2.1.1. from 2.0.4. It appeared to me that new version of Boostrap plugin was trying to use higher version of Resource plugin(1.2-xx) than my default 1.1.6. After rolling back resource plugin to 1.1.6, the error was gone....i hope this is any use

Answer (score 3):

I found my self with the exact same error. However this in my case it was caused by the gwt plugin (version 0.8).

In my case I solved it migrating **ALL** my plugin references from the applicaiton.properties into the BuildConfig.groovy script. Like so:

**From**
application.properties

```
plugins.cloud-foundry=1.2.2
plugins.cloud-support=1.0.11
plugins.hibernate=2.1.1
plugins.jquery=1.7.2
plugins.mail=1.0
plugins.message-digest=1.1
plugins.navigation=1.3.2
plugins.recaptcha=0.5.2
plugins.spock=0.6
plugins.spring-mobile=0.4
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.3
plugins.spring-security-openid=1.0.4
plugins.svn=1.0.0.M1
plugins.tomcat=2.1.1
```

**To** BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        compile ":gwt:0.8"
        compile name:'spring-mobile', version:'0.4'
        compile ":cloud-foundry:1.2.3"
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3"
        compile ":spring-security-openid:1.0.4"
        compile ":cloud-support:1.0.11"
        compile ":hibernate:2.1.1"
        compile ":mail:1.0.1"
        compile ":message-digest:1.1"
        compile ":navigation:1.3.2"
        compile ":recaptcha:0.5.2"
        compile ":spring-mobile:0.4"
        compile ":svn:1.0.0.M1"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.2"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"

        test ":spock:0.6"
    }
```

Hope this help you as well!